# Portable LaTeX fail

Tags: compiling, compilation-error

I installed miktex on a Usb and I try to use TexMaker and TexStudio and I see how to configure. I spent a lot of time doing that and it work's a few times but now when I open miktex and the text editor and I try to compile something it show me this message:

Proceso iniciado: "E:/Latex portable/texmfs/install/miktex/bin/pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "F".tex

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed for the following reason: MiKTeX cannot access file 'E:\Latex portable\texmfs/config\miktex/data/le\texmf.fndb-5' because it is either locked by another MiKTeX program or by the operating system. Remedy: Close running MiKTeX programs and try again. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: E:\Latex portable\texmfs\data\miktex\log\initexmf.log For more information, visit: https://miktex.org/kb/fix-file-in-use

Sorry, but "E:\Latex portable\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe" did not succeed for the following reason: MiKTeX cannot access file 'E:\Latex portable\texmfs/config\miktex/data/le\texmf.fndb-5' because it is either locked by another MiKTeX program or by the operating system. Remedy: Close running MiKTeX programs and try again. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: E:\Latex portable\texmfs\data\miktex\log\pdflatex.log For more information, visit: https://miktex.org/kb/fix-file-in-use

I try to reinstall all the programs again but doesn't work, so I would be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem, but maybe spaces in the path are not a good idea

Comment: I also find it odd that the error message switches between `/` and `\ ` in the path for `texmf`.  Did you copy that message correctly?

Comment: @samcarter is right that one advantage of portable is keeping paths clean short and non system aggressive (no dotted or accented user / folder names) the message you get has two or three common reasons 1)antivirus or other third party file monitoring software (can be due to dissimilar system access e.g. net / cloud drive / ntfs access / uac rights) this can be intermittent but over time usually shows some common cause ~~ 2) the editor is open while your trying to run console tasks (bad idea) ~~ 3) MiKTeX goes ape thinking it is not portable and wants full admin rights (rarely happens but can)

Comment: @Teepeemm that's not unusual I see it all the time on a portable install / is substituted and acceptable in MiKTeX paths especially between generic and dedicated folders

Comment: I just tested holding file open with notepad (which does not lock files) and MiKTeX did not complain simply updating it. Its possible for a dead session in memory to have locked the file or left a system file lock active. In such cases you need to either 1) safely eject the usb & reinsert. 2) look in the folder (with allow view system files active) for a lock file (there should only be 4x fndb files there) 3) close MiKTeX and use task manager to see if there is any rogue copy or related thread stuck in memory 4) fully close the system (restart/reboot) to flush all active file handling threads

Comment: Hi, sorry for not reply you early, I'm in the exam period of the university. @Teepeemm

Comment: @teepeemm I think that I coppied the message correctly.

Comment: @KJo I'm ussing latex in laptops that the university librery let me, not my PC. The laptops dont have antivirus, I will try to re-install all the programs and format my usb. Also I will try to use another usb that I've. I will tell you if I sort out the problem.

Comment: Most common reason is the FNDB is locked open by a process other than MiKTeX-console which is the easiest way to update SO ensure TeXworks or any other application is not interfering with the update

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is your issue solved? How?